# Using math-rm and parse-numbers option in math environment for siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to achieve the following for the number part using the `math-rm` and `parse-number` option in `siunitx`:

```
$[(12+2)\times n]$
```

However, I observe that when I turn the `math-rm` option to `\mathnormal`, the font of number is changed:

```
\begin{align*}
\SI[math-rm=\mathnormal, parse-numbers=false]{[(12+2)\times n]}{g.mol^{-1}}&=\SI{420}{g.mol^{-1}} \\
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{[(12+2)\times n]}{g.mol^{-1}}&=\SI{420}{g.mol^{-1}} 
\end{align*}
```

How can I format the number in the number range as in `$[(12+2)\times n]$` but doesn't change the number font in math environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `\mathnormal`, which changes the math roman font, but `\ensuremath`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\SI[math-rm=\ensuremath, parse-numbers=false]{[(12+2)\times n]}{g.mol^{-1}}&=\SI{420}{g.mol^{-1}} \\
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{[(12+2)\times n]}{g.mol^{-1}}&=\SI{420}{g.mol^{-1}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]